# set <p:tooltip> to Models of <p:schedule> primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

Is there any way to set `tooltip` component to eatch model in `schedule`?

I search something like this:

```
<p:schedule id="idCanlandrier" view="agendaWeek" slotMinutes="30" 
            axisFormat="H:mm" firstHour="8" minTime="7:00" maxTime="20:00"
            value="#{myBean.model}" ignoreTimezone="false">
    <p:tooltip for="modelID" value="value"/>
</p:schedule>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Primefaces 6.0 edition you can set tooltip attribute to p:schedule component to show a description.

`<p:schedule tooltip="true">`

Don't forget to set the *description* to the event in your list.

`e = new DefaultScheduleEvent();`
`e.setDescription("<p:inputText value="Title: " + obj.title + "/>");`

I hope it will helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Sky Games Inc, i will try this later :)

Comment: As far as I can see, that is not possible anymore. Since Primefaces 7.0 it has been removed for security reasons ([schedule: XSS in tooltips #4391](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4391)). Any further ideas anyone?